# Bound service is running but timer won't work if I close the app

Tags: android, service

I'm working on my first Android app and I have a problem with services. I have one activity and one service, in the activity there is a button which calls a method in the service and in the service I have one timer which after 20 seconds shows something in Logcat. In the activity I start the service with startService(intet) and then bind to it in order to keep it working even after closing the activity as it was suggested in many topics.

If I hit the back button or home button the app works properly, but if I hold the home button and then close the app I do not see the log, but if I go to app  manager under the Running tab I can see my app and the service is running!

I do not want to use alarm manager. There reason that I am using a timer here is that I want to make sure my service is really working! I just want to do something in the service and make sure it will work even if the app is closed.

```
public class BoundService extends Service {

    private final IBinder myBinder = new MyLocalBinder();


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        return myBinder;
    }


    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    public void testNotification()
    {
        int interval = 20000; // 20 Second
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
            public void run() {             
                Log.d("BoundService", "Timer");      
            }
        };

        handler.postAtTime(runnable, System.currentTimeMillis()+interval);
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, interval);

    }   

    public class MyLocalBinder extends Binder {
        BoundService getService() {
            return BoundService.this;
        }
    }   
}
```

Activity:

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    BoundService myService;
    boolean isBound = false;





   public void test(View view)
   {
       myService.testNotification();
   }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, BoundService.class);

        startService(intent); 
       bindService(intent, myConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    }


    private ServiceConnection myConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                IBinder service) {
            MyLocalBinder binder = (MyLocalBinder) service;
            myService = binder.getService();
            isBound = true;
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            isBound = false;
        }

       };



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Manual says: "When you create a new Handler, it is bound to the thread / message queue of the thread that is creating it". Thats why your handler works in activity thread and can't continue to process events after activity was killed. Try something like this in your service:

```
Thread worker = null;
Handler handler = null;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    worker = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();
            handler = new Handler();
            Looper.loop();
        }
    });
    worker.start();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    handler.getLooper().quit();
    worker = null;
    handler = null;
}
```

**Edit:**

You must also call startForeground within your service (using some notification) because activity manager kills app process when you closing app if there are no foreground service running and service crashes and will be restarted later because of START_STICKY. It is strange behavior but I saw this on real device too.